# jQuery check if keydown keycode is ASCII

Tags: jquery, localization

If I have code like this I would like to check if the keycode entered is an ASCII A-Z character. My Greek users are telling me this is also picking up Greek characters which I don't want.

```
$(this).on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Not my intention to worry you but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) says: "The KeyboardEvent.keyCode read-only property represents a system and implementation dependent numerical code identifying the unmodified value of the pressed key. This is usually the decimal ASCII (RFC 20) or Windows 1252 code corresponding to the key. If the key can't be identified, this value is 0."

Comment: And in the context of jQuery you should be using `event.which` anyway.

Comment: is it possible to use `keypress` in your script, that should return a typed character only, excluding non-character keys, via `charCode` or `which` as mentioned above comment. then you could apply `fromCharCode` function and compare result against [a...z],[A..Z] scopes, not of their numeric codes